# How to access camera in react-native i can't save picture in my phone storage

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

here is my AndroidMainfest.xml

```
enter code here
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


and here is my code
 import React, { Component, useRef, PermissionsAndroid } from 'react';
 import { View, StatusBar, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';
 import {RNCamera as Camera} from 'react-native-camera';
 import styles from '../src/components/styles'; 
 import PhotoCaptureIcon from '../assets/camera.png'; 
 import CameraRoll from "@react-native-community/cameraroll";


 const checkAndroidPermission = async () => {
    try {
      const permission = PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
      await PermissionsAndroid.request(permission);
      Promise.resolve();
     }catch (error) {
      Promise.reject(error);
    }
};
 export default class Application extends Component { 
     constructor(props) { 
         super(); 
         this.camera = null; 
     } 
 


 takePicture =async () => { 
    if (Platform.OS === 'android'){
        await checkAndroidPermission();
    }
    if (this.camera) {
        const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true };
        const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options);
        console.log(data.uri);
        if (data) {
            const result = await CameraRoll.save(data.uri);
            console.log('result', result);
          }
      }
     
        
    
}


 render() { 
     return (
     <View style={styles.container}>         
      <StatusBar animated hidden /> 
     <Camera 
        ref={ref => {
            this.camera = ref;
          }}
          style={styles.preview}
          type={Camera.Constants.Type.back}
          flashMode={Camera.Constants.FlashMode.off}
          captureAudio={false}
          
         /> 
         <View style={[styles.overlay, styles.bottomOverlay]}> 
             <TouchableOpacity style={styles.captureButton} onPress={this.takePicture}> 
                 <Image source={PhotoCaptureIcon} /> 
             </TouchableOpacity> 
         </View> 
     </View>
     ); 
 }
```

}

and error
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 5):
Error: Permission denied
promiseMethodWrapper@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2242:45
_callee$@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:130062:75
tryCatch@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:24919:23
invoke@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:25092:32
tryCatch@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:24919:23
invoke@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:24992:30
http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:25002:21
tryCallOne@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:26991:16
http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:27092:27
_callTimer@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:30531:17
_callImmediatesPass@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:30570:17
callImmediates@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:30787:33
__callImmediates@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2736:35
http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2522:34
__guard@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2719:15
flushedQueue@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2521:21
flushedQueue@[native code]
invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue@[native code]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `react-native-image-picker` module from npm. and follow the instructions -

[Here on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-picker) you can find the module.

Comment: How to save image in my local storage??

Comment: i can't save imgea in my local storage bacause permission denied

Comment: which database are you using? exp : asynchstorage, sqlite etc

to save an image to phone, you need to ask for the following permission -

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: i use my phone and i already set permission in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: you'll need to configure a database in your project to store data (CRUD) locally.

use asynchstorage or sqlite for that. [find out here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/async-storage) `